# how to crawl html pages to create a total subjective site score

Tags: php, python, shell, web-crawler

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have been exhaustively trying to find/write a utility that does the following:

1. Crawls through a specified site (sitename) looking for various strings (a, b, c, d, e) in all html pages on the site AND a specific named javascript file (javascriptfile.js)
2. If the javascript file is not found on an individual page, output the name/url of the page to a file, and then continue crawling.
3. Create a total score based on how many times each string is found on the page (1 point for each string "a", 2 points for each string "b") etc. etc.

I am stuck at the first part -- because I don't have the coding skills to write the crawling portion.  I have tried Wget, pavuk, mechanize, and some php scripts but they all seem to be limiting as well.

Anyone have any examples or thoughts on how I can use either use or modify one of the mentioned utilities, or write a script would accomplish the above?

I am open C, java, php, perl, etc... -- just want to get this done!

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: `wget -r` will recursively fetch a URL - you'd slurp most of a site that way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [python's urllib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html).

> Fetching Web Pages
>
> Fetching standard Web pages over HTTP is very easy with Python:
>
> import urllib
> f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org") 
> s = f.read() 
> f.close()

--[this is from here](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/HTML.html)

Then use [python's html parser](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html)

Comment: Miriam,   Thanks for the quick response.   I saw the urllib library previously.   I think where I get stuck is loading all of the links, and then processing those individually as well without leaving the actual site.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "loading all of the links"? Certainly once you read with hte urllib, you have all of the links inside. Then when you use the html parser you get them all individually. Are you trying to do all this while still connected to the site? If so, why?

Comment: Miriam,  I certainly don't care whether I remain connected to the site.   What I mean is that after reading the first page, I need to visit all of the links from that page --- and then from those links, visit the links from those pages.   All without repeatedly crawling the same page.   Does that make more sense?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for clarifying, @sdiener. In the example I posted, the entire page contents (including the links that appeared on the page) would be stored in s. You could start parsing s, get to the first link, do your recursive business, and then come back to where you are in s and continue. You wouldn't have to regenerate s, just look at it twice (or multiple times). Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess the only question then is how do I avoid doing the same pages more than once?

Comment: Keep a variable "index" so that you can bookmark your place and come right back to it. That'll probably be the smoothest way.

Answer (score 1):

**Crawls through a specified site (sitename) looking for various strings (a, b, c, d, e) in all html pages on the site AND a specific named javascript file (javascriptfile.js)**

In python you'll want to use urllib. This will allow you to communicate with Http Servers easily.
Then you'll want to look into regexp, this will allow you to do the crawling and the string searching. As most server dont have an open index, you'll need to find `<a>` tags and then strip out everything but where they point, then grab a new destination to crawl to.

> Get The Href Attribute From Anchor Tags
>
> Compare Domains Make Sure They're The Same Or A Relative Path (start with '/')
>
> Repeat Process

You could look into 'beautifulsoup' to help you with this. It'll do all the hard work of reading through HTML for you. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Should even help with search for your strings.

**If the javascript file is not found on an individual page, output the name/url of the page to a file, and then continue crawling.**

You can once again use Beautiful Soup or RegEx here to see if they're infact including it on the page `<script src='urltofile'>`. Then just write the current page you're crawling to a file.

**Create a total score based on how many times each string is found on the page (1 point for each string "a", 2 points for each string "b") etc. etc.**

This will be done everything you're crawling the page, using Regex you can count how many times a specific instance of a text pattern occurs, so you'd just add those to a dict and get your result.
Maybe create a mapping so `score = {'a': 10}; IF a FOUND: points += score['a']*occurences`.

Good Reg-Exp reference: [Regexp Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1):

well, point 1 is really like this(in PHP):

- load html page - you may use `file_get_contents()` or `curl`(recommended) for this
- do some `preg_match`'es on the website looking for things a,b,c and the js script name **OR** use use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php to load pages as XML and do some xpath's on them ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#93637 ) (recommended)

only then you can go over to point 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understood the question, but I think this will help:

Just create a simple crawler, that inserts the data into a database. Then in another PHP file select these rows from the table and then find the specific parts of the crawled text, then give them the value you want. Then update the db.

Here is a crawler code in PHP:

```
<?php
$urls = array("http://www.chilledlime.com");
$parsed = array();

$sitesvisited = 0;

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("db_name");

mysql_query("DROP TABLE search;");
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE search (URL CHAR(255), Contents TEXT);");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE search ADD FULLTEXT(Contents);");

function parse_site() {
    GLOBAL $urls, $parsed, $sitesvisited;

    $newsite = array_shift($urls);

    echo "\n Now parsing $newsite...\n";

    // the @ is because not all URLs are valid, and we don't want
    // lots of errors being printed out
    $ourtext = @file_get_contents($newsite);
    if (!$ourtext) return;

    $newsite = addslashes($newsite);
    $ourtext = addslashes($ourtext);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO simplesearch VALUES ('$newsite', '$ourtext');");

    // this site has been successfully indexed; increment the counter
    ++$sitesvisited;

    // this extracts all hyperlinks in the document
    preg_match_all("/http:\/\/[A-Z0-9_\-\.\/\?\#\=\&]*/i", $ourtext, $matches);

    if (count($matches)) {
        $matches = $matches[0];
        $nummatches = count($matches);

        echo "Got $nummatches from $newsite\n";

        foreach($matches as $match) {

            // we want to ignore all these strings
            if (stripos($match, ".exe") !== false) continue;


            // yes, these next two are very vague, but they do cut out
            // the vast majority of advertising links.  Like I said,
            // this indexer is far from perfect!
            if (stripos($match, "ads.") !== false) continue;
            if (stripos($match, "ad.") !== false) continue;

            if (stripos($match, "doubleclick") !== false) continue;

            // this URL looks safe
            if (!in_array($match, $parsed)) { // we haven't already parsed this URL...
                if (!in_array($match, $urls)) { // we don't already plan to parse this URL...
                    array_push($urls, $match);
                    echo "Adding $match...\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Got no matches from $newsite\n";
    }

    // add this site to the list we've visited already
    $parsed[] = $newsite;
}

while ($sitesvisited < 50 && count($urls) != 0) {
    parse_site();

    // this stops us from overloading web servers
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just an other option *html5lib* More then a year ago it seemed to be a good choice for parsing HTML. see: http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation

Here you go, the example processing this search result page: http://index.hu/24ora?tol=2010-08-25&ig=2011-08-25  ( this is Hungarian) It will extract the number of search results

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from html5lib import treebuilders, treewalkers, serializer
import html5lib
import re
import urllib2
import sys

def openURL (url):
    """
    utlitity function, returns (page, url)
    sets user_agent and resolves possible redirection
    returned url may be different than initial url in the case of a redirect
    """    
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; fr; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091109 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.5"
    request.add_header("User-Agent", user_agent)
    pagefile=urllib2.urlopen(request)
    realurl = pagefile.geturl()
    return (pagefile, realurl)

def daterange(start, stop, step=timedelta(days=1), inclusive=True):
    """
    utility function, returns list of dates within the specified range
    """
    # inclusive=False to behave like range by default
    if step.days > 0:
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start = start + step
            # not +=! don't modify object passed in if it's mutable
            # since this function is not restricted to
            # only types from datetime module
    elif step.days < 0:
        while start > stop:
            yield start
            start = start + step
    if inclusive and start == stop:
        yield start

def processURLindex(url):
    """
    process an url of an index.hu search result page
    returns number of search results
    e.g. http://index.hu/24ora/?s=LMP&tol=2010-04-02&ig=2010-04-02    
    """
    (f, new_url) = openURL(url)
    parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
    tree = parser.parse(f)
    tree.normalize()
    for span in tree.getElementsByTagName("span"):            
        if span.hasAttribute("class") and (span.getAttribute("class") =="talalat"):
            return re.findall(r'\d+', span.firstChild.data)[0]



def daterange2URLindex(term, start_date, end_date):
    urlpattern = "http://index.hu/24ora/?s=$TERM$&tol=2010-04-02&ig=2010-04-02"
    cum = 0
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        datestr = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        url = re.sub(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", datestr, urlpattern)
        url = url.replace("$TERM$", term);
        num = int(processURLindex(url))
        cum = cum + num
        print "\t".join([str(num), str(cum), datestr, url])  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[3], '%Y-%m-%d')
        daterange2URLindex(sys.argv[1], start_date, end_date)
    else:
        print 'search index.hu within a date range; usage:'
        print 'index.hu.py [search term] [from date] [to date] > results.txt'
        print 'the date format is yyyy-mm-dd'
        print 'the output format is TAB delimited and will be the following:'
        print '[count of search results]TAB[count cumulated]TAB[date]TAB[search URL for that date]'
        sys.exit(-1)
```